# Program to implement the is_same_type type trait in c++

Tags: c++, types, traits

HI Could anyone give a sample program to implement the is_same_type type trait in c++?

Comment: Sure, if you provide a detailed specification of what such a program should do. We all sit around here waiting for requests just like this - give us the spec and we will be right on it!

Comment: This isn't really a "write the program for me" as much as a "I heard about this thing and I have no idea how to do it, but I think I need it" request.  Agreed; its not the best question in the world, but I don't think it really violates any guidelines, except not being very specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T1, typename T2 >
struct is_same_type      { enum { result = false }; };

template< typename T>
struct is_same_type<T,T> { enum { result = true }; };


int main()
{
    std::cout << is_same_type<int,float>::result << '\n'
              << is_same_type<char,char>::result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `enum {result = true}`, rather than `static const bool result = true`?  Won't the `enum` give `result` the wrong type?

Comment: So you are setting yourself up as a program writing service now?  This really doesn't help the OP (or you) in the long run.

Comment: @Brooks: The only reason is that I did TMP when the `enum` trick was still hip and more portable anyway. I agree that nowadays it should be `static const bool result = ...`, but I keep forgetting this...

Comment: I'm curious about the enum {} thing too.  I've seen this in other code but have only been able to speculate about why its happening.

Comment: @Neil: Usually I'm among the first to jump on anyone who seems to post homework questions without a proper tag, but I seriously doubt anyone but me would give their students a TMP problem for homework. And, yes, absent of the homework problem, if people politely ask whether someone could show them something, and if that something is easy enough so that I happen to able to be make it up in <3mins, I don't usually hesitate to show them. That (and the fact that others are quick in pointing out my errors) is what I'm here for, after all.

Comment: @sbi Well, I disagree. I too routinely provide provide compilable C++ code in my answers (in fact I always try to ensure the code is compilable - don't always succeed)  but ONLY if the OP also put in some effort. But of course you must reply to posts as you see fit.

Comment: Hi this by no means is an Home Work.. I am just very confused about Templates and Type Traits.. I tried looking up a lot of sites but have not found a single one which in simple correct term explain type traits or Templates.. I decided the next best way to learn is to read from code samples and try to figure out the pieces.. If any body experienced have a better way to understand Meta Programming and Type traits I will be glad and thankful..

Comment: @Srinivasa: Get a copy of *"Modern C++ programming"*, it should get you started.

Comment: You could try some books. If you are comfortable with templates in C++, Meta Template Programming by David Abrahams and Alexei Gurtovoy is a must read :)

Comment: I am a beginner to Template Programming in C++ and it looks and sounds so very different from all the c++  I had learned earlier.

Comment: @Srinivasa: Then maybe a more basic book would be better (like *"C++ Templates The Complete Guide"*) - note that there is a C++ book list on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Srinivasa: If you want to learn about traits, Nathan Myers' classic http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html might be the first publication on it. I second the recommendation of _C++ Templates The Complete Guide_. It's got all the basics you need to understand templates. You can take it from there. Both _Modern C++ Design_ and _C++ Template Metaprogramming_ are great books, but might be a bit tall for someone who doesn't know enough of the basics of templates.