# Can a template function compare the two typenames?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program to implement the is_same_type type trait in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639557/program-to-implement-the-is-same-type-type-trait-in-c)

I want my template function to do something differently based on whether the two typenames are equal or not:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> f()
{
  if (T1==T2) ...;
  else ...;
}
```

I know "if(T1==T2)" is not gonna working, but, is there a way to do it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: @NPE this is not a duplicate IMHO. Properly applying `is_same` is different from just implementing it. What if he will be doing `T2 t; T1 *u = &t;` in the true branch? Compilation will fail if he uses above `if` for types `char` and `int` respectively.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: You're right. Can't undo the vote, but will cease casting close votes for the rest of the day. :)

Answer (score 18):

You can check the [`boost::is_same`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html) or [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) in C++11.

So, it would be something like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> f()
{
  if (boost::is_same<T1,T2>::value) ...;
  else ...;
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between those two that you decided to use `boost` instead?

Comment: Not really. I am simply more familiar with boost, as it had worked long before C++11.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename A, typename B> void f() {

    if ( std::is_same<A, B>::value ) {

        //

    }

}
```

<sub>`std::is_same` returns a `typedef` of a boolean (true, false) depending on the equlity of the types `A` and `B`</sub>

Answer (score 4):

If the types can be inferred and are not being explicitly passed, you could make two separate functions:

```
template<typename SameType>
void f(SameType x, SameType y)
{
    // ...
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void f(T1 x, T2 y)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specialize the template

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void f()
{
  //The else part goes here
}

template<typename T>
void f()
{
  //The if part goes here
}
```

Comment: downvoter wants to elaborate on what's wrong?

Comment: For the second one, don't you mean just template<typename T>? The version you just posted does not compile.

Comment: @SplinterOfChaos, I do... shuold have proof read it one more time

Comment: It is not a specialization, it is overloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `typeid` of `T1` and `T2`

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T1, typename T2> void f()
{
    bool a;
    if (typeid(T1) == typeid(T2))
        a = true;
    else
        a = false;
}
```

Comment: While it is also a solution, note that typeid is resolved at run time. It introduces performance overhead and both branches will be present in the function. I believe the compile-time evaluation of the condition is preferred.

Comment: And it will not work for `f<int, const int>` or `f<const int&, int&&>` since the typeid for all of them is equal.